# USBDEVFS_RESET vs IOCTL_USB_RESET

Tags: linux, usb, ioctl

I seem tangled between different abstractions on the USB stack.. what is the difference betweeen `IOCTL_USB_RESET` and `USBDEVFS_RESET` fired against an USB device? Will both calls finally trigger the same low level actions on the interface, or is there a difference?

I noticed that `USBDEVFS_RESET` is sometimes described with 'equivalent of replugging and reenumerating the device', while I found by myself that firing `IOCTL_USB_RESET` (as done by libusb's `usb_reset()` call) does trigger a reset message in `dmesg` but no new 'enumeration', which would lead to the usual multi-line USB detection and identification messages I guess.

As `IOCTL_USB_RESET` is not feasable to solve my problems (stuck up usb devices), and even does not trigger reenumeration, is there any chance `USBDEVFS_RESET` would do better?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking about `IOCTL_USBFS_RESET` instead of `IOCTL_USB_RESET`?

`IOCTL_USBFS_RESET` is specific to `libusb`. Indeed, `libusb` does not use structures nor ioctls defined in `usbdevice_fs.h`. Instead it redefine everything in `os/linux_usbfs.h` (I think for historical reasons). These two headers are binary compatible but, `libusb` does not use same names for structures and ioctls. For structures, prefix `usbdevfs_` is replaced with `usbfs_` (`usbfs_ctrltransfer`, `usbfs_bulktransfer`, ...). For ioctls, prefix `USBDEVFS_` is replaced by `IOCTL_USBFS_`.

So, indeed, `IOCTL_USBFS_RESET` is the same than `USBDEVFS_RESET` (= `_IO('U', 20)`).